# Mnist data image and label mismatch

Tags: python, mnist

I know this could be a stupid question but I really can’t figure out why. Below is the code that I tried to print a single  image and label with same index from train data at

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import      input_data
import tensorflow as tf

mndata = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

images_train=mndata.train.images    # training set
labels_train=mndata.train.labels    
images_test=mndata.test.images     # testing set
labels_test=mndata.test.labels

##### Testing single image to network

train_index=4

image = images_train[train_index]
label = labels_train[train_index]

plt.imshow(image.reshape(28,28))
plt.show()  
print('label',label)
```

The image shown as one
But label is [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 1.]

Comment: and you sure all other "ones" are not encoded the same way? You're using a `one_hot` encoder, there's no reason for it to assume `1` should be in the second place. So as long as all images with the same number have the same label, nothing's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

in the file "train-labels.idx1-ubyte" you have an offset, look:

[offset] [type]          [value]          [description]

0000     32 bit integer  0x00000801(2049) magic number (MSB first)

0004     32 bit integer  10000            number of items

0008     unsigned byte   ??               label

0009     unsigned byte   ??               label

........

xxxx     unsigned byte   ??               label

Add an offset of 8 and it will be done!

sources: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/